# PHPStorm Formatting Fury

Tags: php, drupal, coding-style, code-formatting, phpstorm

Having completely abandoned the utter nightmares that I have had with Eclipse based IDE's I've decided to try another. PHP Storm seems nice, it's fast and I'm using the trial now.

One of the main issues I've had with my last IDEs is SVN...and the other is FORMATTING. It seems that formatters like to just abandon their settings if you do more than 10 lines at a time and I am going out of my mind trying to set this up.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$items['system/person/%company/%person/renew_comp/%comp_type/%competency'] = array(
            'title' => t('Renew Competency'),
            'description' => 'Renew competency',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'access arguments' => array('administer consultant competencies'),
            'page arguments' => array('consultancy_competency_renew_form', 2, 3, 5, 6),
    );
```

And NO MATTER WHAT settings I use when I format my page (I'm using drupal standards), it messes it up. Either sticks it in one big line, or keeps everything nice and tidy like it is, sorts the indent to how I want it, but just inexplicably fires each of the numbers in the sub arrays at the end there on to its own line at the bottom.

The most infuriating is that I will tinker with the settings and think I have it sussed when I highlight one array and format and it looks nice:

```
$items['system/person/%company/%person/renew_comp/%comp_type/%competency'] = array(
    'title' => t('Renew Competency'),
    'description' => 'Renew competency',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access arguments' => array('administer consultant competencies'),
    'page arguments' => array('consultancy_competency_renew_form', 2, 3, 5, 6),
  );
```

...then I'll highlight the whole page and THAT SAME ARRAY will suddenly look like this:

```
$items['system/person/%company/%person/renew_comp/%comp_type/%competency'] = array(
      'title' => t('Renew Competency'),
      'description' => 'Renew competency',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'access arguments' => array('administer consultant competencies'),
      'page arguments' => array(
        'consultancy_competency_renew_form',
        2,
        3,
        5,
        6
      ),
    );
```

THE SAME ARRAY! What is the point in an auto formatter than I can't trust to not completely naff up my code?

Now I know that this is because of the settings. But is there a setting for LEAVE MY ARRAYS ALONE? Just sort the tab intent, don't stick em on one line, dont give me 15 new lines for every key-value, just play nice.

So, please, can you help me out here

Thankyou

Comment: Very odd, whether selecting a specific part or the entire page, the output should be the same. This sounds like a bug, I think you'd best report it at the [Jetbrains issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard) so they can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! After literally hours of shouting an such...it was because the right margin was set too far to the left. The margin was also set to not show, so I had no idea.

Why this did this only when the whole page was selected I don't know, but it works now so I don't care. Have emailed them tho and told them this, maybe a bug still

Answer (score 0):

I think the formatting is different because it is in the context of itself vs. the whole page.

As for the whole page formatting, this looks like it is as it should be based on the code style settings.  If you go to settings->code Style->PHP then wrapping and braces you will see the array initializer towards the bottom.  This is what is telling phpstorm how to format your arrays.  Hope it helps someone.